# Finding Local Application Exploits? (Black-Box)

Tags: exploit, fuzzing

I am new to exploit development, and I am wondering how I could go about fuzzing a local application (e.g. Windows Media Player) using software if I did not have access to the source code. I have basic-intermediate knowledge of buffer overflow vulnerabilities, how they work, how to find them and how to write exploits for them. I just need the 2nd step - finding them in the first place...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuzzing is a useful tool but not necessarily easy. I'd suggest starting with listening to [some talks online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xnwodi2CBws) on fuzzing or doing some reading. The big picture is that you want to find a way to generate random/mutated input and then script your application to run with this random input. So for Windows Media Player, you might start by:

1. Figuring out how to run WMP in an automated/scripted way.
2. Looking for tools to generate fuzzed file input.